# Vectors a and b are non collinear...

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Vectors a and b are non collinear. Which values of scalar Λ conform to vectors Λa + b and 3a+Λb being collinear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Vectors are collinear if they are scalar multiples of each other. Hence, $\Lambda a + b$ and $3a+\Lambda b$ are collinear iff $(\Lambda x, x) = (3, \Lambda)$.

Can you finish the problem?